# How to open a specific VS Code profile in a dev container using the code command

Tags: vscode-remote

I am using GitHub Codespaces, which runs a Docker container inside a virtual machine. I want to open VS Code with a specific profile when launching a repository using the `code` command. I know that there is a `--profile` option for the VS Code CLI that can be used to specify the profile name, like this:

```
code <repository> --profile=“vscode-profile-name”
```

I would like to know at which stage of the lifecycle it is best to execute this command so that the VS Code instance that opens uses the specified profile. Can anyone provide guidance on how to do this in a dev container?

Thank you.